# Сортировка SQL запроса

Tags: sql, сортировка, order

Здравствуйте. Подскажите. 
Есть таблица, которая генерируется в SQL формата

```
 код товара | наименование | закуп | прод|
  001       | товар1       | 5     | 4   |
```

первые два столбца в строке у меня выводятся обычным Select, а там где закуп и прол считается сумма в других таблицах и выводится итоговое значение.

```
 SELECT COALESCE(SUM(quant), 0.0) AS quant
FROM paid_items, paid
WHERE 
   paid.record_type=-1
```

В одном столбце считается по -1, во втором по +1.
Я хочу чтобы сортировалось в итоге по третьему столбцу. От большего к меньшему, но не могу понять как правильно указать сортировку, пытался в ORDERS BY засунуть это условие полностью, но ничем, понятное дело, это не помогло

Comment: Вам группировка или сортировка нужна?

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, корректный вопрос. Пока что он в виде "как мне организовать прогулку по полу, если я люблю помидорки?"

Comment: ошибся, сортировка конечно

Comment: Нужно писать `ORDER BY COALESCE(SUM(quant), 0.0)`

Comment: Смотрите, есть таблица, которая генерируется в SQL формата
код товара | наименование | закуп | прод|
 001            | товар1              | 5       |  4     |
первые два столбца в строке у меня выводятся обычным Select, а там где закуп и прол считается сумма в других таблицах и выводится итоговое значение.
И я хочу чтобы сортировалось именно по этиой сумме. От большего к меньшему

Comment: @Сергей обновите вопрос, под ним есть кнопка `править`. Приведенный запрос в вопросе не соответствует вашему комментарию. Покажите запрос который хотите выполнить и укажите что конкретно в нем не получается.

Comment: поправил первоначальное сообщение, извиняюсь

Comment: Все равно вы не привели ваш запрос. Вы же сортировку хотите не во вложенном запросе, а во основном.

Comment: В выражении сортировки можно указывать порядковый номер поля выходного набора: `ORDER BY 3`